# Bokeh hover doesn't work with the value zero when y_range.start is not provided

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

Bokeh hover doesn't work with the value zero when y_range.start is not provided, for example, in the case of following code, the hover doesn't display the count '0' when we hover the mouse on Nectarines.

```
    from bokeh.io import show, output_file
    from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
    from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6
    from bokeh.plotting import figure
    from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap
    output_file("colormapped_bars.html")
    fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
    counts = [5, 3, 0, 2, 5, 6]
    data = {'fruits' : fruits, 'counts'   : counts}
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(fruits=fruits, counts=counts))
    p = figure(x_range=fruits, plot_height=250, toolbar_location=None, title="Fruit Counts", tools="hover", tooltips="Count: @counts")
    p.vbar(x='fruits', top='counts', width=0.9, source=source, legend="fruits", line_color='white', fill_color=factor_cmap('fruits', palette=Spectral6, factors=fruits))
    p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None

    show(p)
```

But if I add **p.y_range.start = 0**, the hover works.
Also hover doesn't work when there is negative range, like **p.y_range.start** = -5

Please help me what wrong I am doing here.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are expecting. Default "point" hover for a glyph is based on there being a presence on the screen (i.e. actual pixel real estate taken up). Your "Nectarines" bar has zero-height, and therefore takes up no space on the screen. As far as "point" hit-testing for hover goes (the default mode), it is more or less an invisible target. (If it "works" under any circumstances it's almost certainly accidental due to rounding issues.)

If you want the hover to pop up whenever the cursor is *anywhere* above a bar's category, you can set:

```
p.hover.mode = "vline"
```

This is a different hover mode that is able to "see" even  zero-height bars

[image]

Comment: This is what I am looking for, works perfectly. Big thanks @bigreddot

Comment: If this is the correct answer, an a "accept"  would be appreciated.

Comment: oh yeah, sorry I forgot